# Optimize nginx with minify for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, minify

I recently rent a vServer and now I am playing around with nginx, fastcgi cache and my wordpress setup. It's running pretty fast right now but in all speed test I came across my js and css files. Is there some kind of minifying implemented in nginx I could use? Also my pictures galleries do have a lot of pictures, is there something else I could use to increase the performance? (all pictures are stripped down to a minimum file size already)

This is my nginx.config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and my host file:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/blog;
index index.php;
server_name IPADRESS;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#Cache everything by default
set $no_cache 0;
#Don't cache POST requests
if ($request_method = POST)
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}
#Don't cache if the URL contains a query string
if ($query_string != "")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}
#Don't cache the following URLs
if ($request_uri ~* "/(administrator/|login.php)")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}
#Don't cache if there is a cookie called PHPSESSID
if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}
}
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ .php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
        expires 365d;
}
}
```

I don't want to install a plugin just for this stuff (keep Wordpress as simple as possible) so I am looking for the best basic setup for wordpress.

Comment: Why would nginx do the minifying? It's like asking for car engine to control your windscreen wipers when it rains...

Comment: Why not? If you could say "Minify all CSS and JS files automatically" it would be a blast :)

Comment: Because server isn't something that does logical processing, such as "if X then minify file x". It simply takes a request and passes it along, when reply is ready it sends it back. It's up to you to decide that you want to serve minified file, not to instruct the server to do it. Also, it shouldn't be difficult to remove newlines and unnecessary whitespace on your own from those files.

Comment: nginx is capable to perform such processes but I am not sure how to implement the module. Maybe there is something better for nginx